# 受信したメールをDBに保存する際に特定のメールのみ文字化けが発生する

Tags: php, 文字化け, 文字コード

phpでメールを受信した際に、受信したメールから「差出人」「件名」「本文」を抽出してDBに保存する処理を作成しました。
テストして正常に動作することを確認したのですが、特定の差出人からメールのみ「本文」が文字化けして保存されてしまいます。メーラーソフトで見るぶんには文字化けは発生しないので、メールそのものには問題がないかと考えているのですが・・・

文字化けするメールの文字コードは「utf-8」なのですが、
「utf-8」のメールすべてが文字化けするのではなく、現状一部のメールのみ文字化けします。
文字化けするのはあくまで「本文」のみで「件名」は日本語であっても文字化けは発生しません。

文字化けする原因はどのようなことが考えられるでしょうか？

▼以下のようなコードを書いています。

```
// メールの処理開始
mb_language('ja');
mb_internal_encoding("utf-8");

// メール取得
if ( ($stdin=fopen("php://stdin",'r')) == true ){
    while( !feof($stdin) ){
        $line .= fgets($stdin,4096);
    }
}
fclose($stdin);


// PEAR を使った処理
$decoder = & new Mail_mimeDecode( $line ); // MIMEを分解
$parts = $decoder->getSendArray();
list( $recipients, $headers, $body ) = $parts;

$subject = mb_decode_mimeheader( $headers['Subject'] ) ;
$from = mb_decode_mimeheader( $headers['From'] ) ;
$m_body = trim(mb_convert_encoding( $body, "UTF-8", 'ASCII, JIS, UTF-8, SJIS' ));

//以下DBに保存する処理
```

▼文字化けしたメールの一部です

```
  =E2=96=BC=E9=80=A3=E7=B5=A1=E5=B8=8C=E6=9C=9B=
 =E6=97=A5/=E6=99=82=E9=96=93=E5=B8=AF


 =E2=96=BC=E8=BB=8A=E6=A4=
 =9C=E6=BA=80=E4=BA=86=E6=97=A5
 2018-10-17
```

Comment: 文字化けの原因としては色々可能性があり得るので、もう少し文字化けする事例についての情報をご提示いただいた方が原因が判明しやすいだろうと思います。せめて、文字化けした後のメール本文の一部だけでもご提示いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。メールの一部追記しました

Comment: 文字化けが起こるメールのヘッダーの`content-type`と`content-transfer-encoding`には何が書かれていますか？

Comment: これは文字化けではなく、quoted-printable というフォーマットになります(一行目は「連絡希望」)。

Comment: すでに指摘されているように文字化けというよりはquoted-printableが正しくデコードできていない状態です。データ自体は「`▼連絡希望日/時間帯`//`▼車検満了日`/`2018-10-17`」なんてのを表す正しいquoted-printableデータなので、`Mail_mimeDecode`が正しく動作していないものと思われます。Mail_mimeDecodeの古いバージョン(1.5.5かそれ以前のもの)にはこの辺が誤動作する致命的なバグがあったことが報告されているんですが、使用されているのは最新版の1.5.6になっているでしょうか。最新版なのにこの現象が起こるのであれば、考えにくいですが、メールの`content-transfer-encoding`ヘッダが壊れていることになります。

Comment: ライブラリのバージョン確認方法がわからなかったのですが
https://pear.php.net/package/Mail_mimeDecode/download
からダウンロードした最新の
mimeDecode.php
を現在アップされているmimeDecode.phpと比較したところ同一内容でしたので
おそらく最新版なのかと考えています。

文字化けしているメールのヘッダーは以下のようになっていました。

Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。残念ながら「pear.php.net/package/Mail_mimeDecode/downloadの最新版」→ちゃんと先のバグの修正は当たっている。「Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8」どちらも正常でMail_mimeDecodeが(バグありの旧バージョンですら)正しく処理するはずの内容、と言うことで私の知識の範囲では現在は手詰まりです。何か気づいたことがあればまた書き込みますが、それまでに無事に解決できることを願っております。

Comment: Mail_mimeDecodeのソースとにらめっこして、ようやく自分がMail_mimeDecodeの仕様を勘違いしていたことに気がつきました。`getSendArray()`では、上記のような「quoted-printableをデコードする」ような処理は走りません。(`getSendArray()`は、メール送信に使う内容を切り出すメソッド。)適切な引数を指定して`decode()`メソッドを呼んでやらないといけません。ちと直接検証できる環境がないため、細かいところご自身で修正していただかないといけないかもしれませんが、回答の形で書いてみます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメントに書いた通りですが、Mail_mimeDecodeは`getSendArray()`を呼んでも、quoted-printableやbase64でエンコードされたメール本文をデコードしてくれません。正しくデコードさせてやるには`decode()`メソッドを呼ぶ必要があります。

`// PEAR を使った処理`以下の行を、次のように書き換えてください。

```
// PEAR を使った処理
$decoder = & new Mail_mimeDecode( $line ); // MIMEを分解
$decoded = $decoder->decode(
    'include_bodies' => true,
    'decode_bodies' => true,
    'decode_headers' => false, //<-(1)
]);

$subject = mb_decode_mimeheader( $decoded->headers['subject'] ) ; //<-(2)
$from = mb_decode_mimeheader( $decoded->headers['from'] ) ; //<-(2)
$m_body = trim(mb_convert_encoding( $decoded->body, "UTF-8", 'ASCII, JIS, UTF-8, SJIS' ));

//以下DBに保存する処理
```

最近のメールクライアントでは、UTF-8メールを送信するのにquoted-pritableもbase64も使わないものが多いので、文字化けするものの方が少なかったかもしれませんが、一般的には対応しておかないとまずいものです。

他の種類の文字化けまでは保証できませんが、少なくとも`=`がやたら出てくるquoted-printableの文字列がそのまま登録されることはなくなるはずです。コメントに書いたように一部修正していただかないといけないかもしれませんが、お試しください。

---

と言うわけで、質問者の @たーとるず さんのお力もお借りして上記のコードを修正しました。

(1) `'decode_headers' => true,`を指定した元のコードでは、ヘッダー内容のデコード処理がMail_mimeDecode側と、`mb_decode_mimeheader`によるものと二重に走っていました。Mail_mimeDecode側のデコード処理はいまいちあてにできなさそうなので、`mb_decode_mimeheader`だけで処理するよう、値を`false`に変更しました。

(2) MIMEのヘッダー名は大文字小文字無視が原則ですが、PHPの連想配列はそのような「大文字小文字無視」した検索ができないので、なんらかの方法で表記を統一してやる必要があります。Mail_mimeDecodeではMIMEの仕様にあるような「頭字大文字」ではなく「全部小文字」と言う動作になっていたので、キー文字列をそれに合わせて変更しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます、こちらで文字化け解決しました。ただ、$subjectと$fromの値が空になってしまうのですが、原因わかりませんでしょうか。

Comment: @たーとるず さん、ご報告ありがとうございます。空になってしまう件ですが、`Mail_mimeDecode`の`decode()`処理でヘッダーのキー文字列を全部小文字に書き換えているせいかもしれません。キー名を`'Subject'`, `'From'`から`'subject'`, `'from'`に書き換えてみてください。

Comment: @たーとるず さん、小出しになって申し訳ありませんが、もし上記の修正で「空ではない値が取れるようになったが、文字化けすることがある」と言う場合、回答中のコード`'decode_headers' => true,`を`'decode_headers' => false,`に書き換えてみてください。

Comment: キー名の書き換えと、'decode_headers' => false,に書き換えで正常に動作しました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @たーとるず さん、ご報告ありがとうございます。ご確認いただいた内容で、回答の方修正させていただきます。